# C# MVC Cross-Site Scripting (XSS) Prevention

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, security, penetration-testing

I have an admin site in .Net (MVC) which provides an open field in which we have given an option to users to enter formatted text, user can style the text include links, etc. Same feature which stack overflow is providing while posting a question.

HTML entered in the text field is encoded in the post call, & lt ; for <, & gt ; for > and so on. but javascript code is not.

CheckLink[ ** checkscript ** ]( jaVasCriPt : eval ( a t o b  ('YWxlcnQoJ3Rlc3QzMzMnKQ==') ) )
------I have to write the above code so as to display on Comments.----------

This creates an alert message, someone can exploit it.

There are libraries which can be used to encode the HTML, but we do not want to present the encoded text as we want the links to be displayed in public view.
So if I encode the incoming request on the server using .Net XSS library, or Web.Security (getsafehtml or HttpUtility.encode) then the links and all remaining stuff is encoded.

Development

1) Is there any library which would blacklist javascript functions - jaVasCriPt:eval or encode them leaving HTML as it is.
I would like to take out javascript code or flag them with validation but allow other text formatting features I have provided without compromising with security.

=================

## Any library (in C#) that can raise an exception when there is Unsafe javascript in the posted data is something I am looking for.

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

If user needs to enter html markup then I recommend you to use `[AllowHtml]` attribute on model.
If you still get an error on your post method you can use `[ValidateInput(false)]` attribute but it's not a very secure way. Then you can use [Antixss library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.security.antixss?view=netframework-4.5) to encode it. Plus always use `AntiForgeryToken`.

Comment: I have gone through Antixss. So Markdowndeep editor which I am using takes care of HTML encoding. I am not worried about posting this data to server, as these links getting displayed on Public site is what is expected.

Any library that can raise an exception when there is Unsafe javascript in the posted data is something I am looking for.